# Using Lambda in Python with a Dictionary

Tags: python, lambda

Yesterday I asked a question about using a dictionary and lambda, [Yesterdays question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30710631/dictionary-executing-code-assigned-to-it-without-being-called?noredirect=1#comment49482341_30710631), however I still can't get this to work, see code below,

```
lookupDictionary = input()
dictionaryTest = {
    lambda : file1.write(variableTowrite)
}
dictionaryTest.get(lookupDictionary)
```

Any help?

Comment: your `dictionaryTest`is NOT a `dict`, it's a `set`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `lambda` is supposed to be *in addition to* the 1, not replacing it. And you need to call the function you get from the dict.

```
lookupDictionary = input()
dictionaryTest = {
    1 : lambda: file1.write(variableTowrite)
}
dictionaryTest.get(lookupDictionary)()
```

Comment: Now I just get the error, TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: If you're in Python 3.X, `input` is returning a string rather than an integer, and `dictionaryTest` doesn't have any keys that are strings. You probably have to do `dictionaryTest[int(lookupDictionary)]()`.

Comment: Solved, it was no inverted commas on the 1.